# iOS 12 device audio player speaker and microphone not working simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift

I have played and record audio simultaneously in iOS 12 device but it audio play from speaker and audio record from the microphone so I need to audio play and record both thing through a microphone which is working fine with iOS 9 or less device.

How can I achieve this thing play and record simultaneously through a microphone in iOS 12 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an answer. please check below code for better Understanding:

```
    do {
       if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
            try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        } else {
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().perform(NSSelectorFromString("setCategory:error:"), with: AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord)
        }
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("failed to record!")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if we want to use both of them at a time we need to set `AVAudioSession`'s Category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Let me check this solution.

Comment: If not work, try this sequence -> first start recording, then play audio.

Comment: I have added this solution. It plays video from the microphone but the recording of audio is not working. I have nearby the solution of the above problem.

Would you please do need full for me? Thank you.